# How to get formatted XML out of Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm inexperience with Oracle and am having trouble exporting my data as XML. I've managed to get this query working, but the format of the XML seems fixed and won't work for me. Here's the query:

```
SELECT value(em).getClobVal() AS "output"
    FROM table(XMLSequence(Cursor
      (   
          SELECT * FROM UserMain
       )
)) em
```

What I get from this is:

```
  <ROW><STATUS>Active</STATUS><NAME>Joe Smith<NAME><PHONE>234-2345</PHONE>...</ROW>
  <ROW><STATUS>Inactive</STATUS><NAME>Sally Smith<NAME><PHONE>234-4444</PHONE>...</ROW>
  etc.
```

But what I want is this, with the XML tags "ROWS" around the outside of the output, as shown here:

```
  <ROWS>
      <RECORD><STATUS>Active</STATUS><NAME>Joe Smith<NAME><PHONE>234-2345</PHONE>...</RECORD>
      <RECORD><STATUS>Inactive</STATUS><NAME>Sally Smith<NAME><PHONE>234-4444</PHONE>...</RECORD>
      etc.
  </ROWS>
```

So what do I need to do with my query to change  to  and put outer tags around the output?

Answer (score 5):

There is a trick I've found some years ago. If you use the `XMLTYPE` and apply some XSL template to this `XMLTYPE` using Oracle `transform` function, there is an unexpected behaviour: XML becomes formatted. It is very unexpected and from some point of view funny.

This `procedure` does the trick:

```
procedure beautify(xmlout in out nocopy clob)
  is
    xml    xmltype := new xmltype(xmlout);
    xsl    xmltype := new xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><DOCUMENT></DOCUMENT>');
    tmp    xmltype;
begin
  tmp := xml.transform(xsl,null);
  xmlout := xml.getclobval;

  if tmp is null then null; end if;
end;
```

Of course, you should pass to the function a valid `XMLTYPE`, e.g. in your case it should be kind of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<DOCUMENT>
  <ROW><STATUS>Active</STATUS><NAME>Joe Smith<NAME><PHONE>234-2345</PHONE>...</ROW>
  <ROW><STATUS>Inactive</STATUS><NAME>Sally Smith<NAME><PHONE>234-4444</PHONE>...</ROW>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Please, note that `encoding="iso-8859-1"` is used for German language, you should change it to use the encoding for your purposes.

If you want to use this in query you can create a `function` instead of `procedure`. Also you can add the additional rows before formatting and remove it after formatting.

This works well in Oracle 11.2

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Let me try that out.

Comment: Just to inform that this is by design.

In oracle documentation you will find the following:

`XMLType methods (member functions) extract() and transform() always pretty-print.`

[Link to Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm#i1024803)

Answer (score 1):

The answer above worked OK, but this is eventually what I went with as a solution because it was simpler for the complete implementation:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(dbms_xmlgen.getxml
('Select * from USRMAIN'),'ROWSET','rows'),'ROW','records') 
 as output from dual
```

The data/functional portion is this:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('Select * from USRMAIN') output from dual
```

This code basically worked like a cursor, serializing the output of the query inside adding the "< fieldname>value< /fieldname>" for each value, with "< ROW>< /ROW>" at the beginning and end of each row, plus < ROWSET>< /ROWSET>.

Then I effectively wrapped the output in two Replace() statements to change the default headers returned in the data from Oracle.

Hopefully this is of use to someone else ...

Comment: This blog post describes four different methods: http://rwijk.blogspot.nl/2009/03/pulling-xml-out-of-database.html. Hopefully it is of use.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I'm not good with Oracle, but I'll take a look at those methods.