# how to create XML tree when sql query return multiple rows

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle10g

I have table( tab1) which join 2 table called tab2 which can return multiple row. I also join to tab3 which return only unique row

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM tab1 
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.col1=tab2.col2 
LEFT JOIN tab3 ON tab1.col1=tab3.col1
```

I need a result in XML format

```
<JOB>
<col1>1<col1>
<tab2>
<col2>1<\col2>
<col3>2<\col3>
<\tab2>
<tab2>
<col2>4<\col2>
<col3>5<\col3>
<\tab2>
<\JOB>
```

is there any way i can do this in sql
pls let me know if you need more info

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479736/how-to-get-formatted-xml-out-of-oracle)?

Comment: no my problem is i want to create a set when there are multiple rows for tab2 in the same xml tag. check from tab2 to \tab2.

Comment: The columns are a part of which table? What do the numbers inside the tags denote?  Why is there no tab3 mentioned? What have you tried? Why do you need in XML?

Comment: `select xmlelement("JOB", xmlforest(col1), xmlagg(xmlelement("TAB2", xmlforest(col2, col3))))
    from tab1
         left join tab2 on col1 = col2
         left join tab3 on col1 = col3
group by col1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a XML documnet by 2 ways.

1) Using constructor of XMLTYPE

```
DECLARE
   l_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN l_refcursor FOR SELECT employee_id
                             , first_name
                             , job_id
                          FROM employee 
                          join emplyee
                          on employee_id = empid;


   l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(l_refcursor);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
END;
/
```

2) Using `DBMS_XMLGEN` package. DBMS_XMLGEN built-in is similar to the XMLTYPE constructor, but accepts a query directly:

```
DECLARE
   l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    l_xmltype := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT employee_id
                                             , first_name
                                             , job_id
                                          FROM employee 
                                          join emplyee
                                          on employee_id = empid'
                                       );

    dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
END;
/
```